# How to make a Non-scrollable ListView with dynamic number of rows based on the number of items

Tags: android

**The Problem**

I have unknown number of square icons of the same size that should be displayed in a horizontal list however in case the number icons exceed a certain number the new icons should be displayed in the new row, and in case I have 1 item it should be displayed at the center it should be displayed at the center not at the left.

So this for example if I have 4 items.

### [image: 4 Items]

If I have 5 items and the screen is already filled with 4, the 5th item should be displayed in the next row and centered.

[image: 4 Items + 1 centered in the a second row]

Comment: i think you don't need any listview for this just take linearlayout and add your view inside this layout just like parent.addView(childView); and play with gravity according to no of child

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use ListView for that. If you can fix the number of items in a single row say 5, then you simply have a RelativeLayout and add your items to that dyanmically.For eg. like this.

```
RelativeLayout rl_attendingLayout=new RelativeLayout(yourActivity.this);

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfImages; i++) {
        ImageView temp = new ImageView(yourActivity.this);

        temp.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        temp.setId(i + 1);
        temp.setTag(Integer.valueOf(i + 1));

        // set Image to ImageView

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams attendingParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                imagewidth, imagewidth);
        if (i >= 5) {
            attendingParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, (i % 5)
                    + (int) (5 * ((i / 5) - 1)) + 1);
            if (i % 5 > 0) {
                attendingParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, i);
            }
        } else {
            if (i > 0) {
                attendingParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, i);
            } else {
                attendingParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
                attendingParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            }
        }

        attendingParams.setMargins(margin, 0, 0, margin);
        temp.setLayoutParams(attendingParams);

        rl_attendingLayout.addView(temp);
    }
```